# Shall I trust client side data blindly in web application?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, web-applications

I have JSP/HTML pages on client side in my web application. Suppose i have a `<select>` control with all country name. When submit button is clicked it will go to server side spring controller and will be handled their.

Now my question is shall I validate country name on server side or I should trust that `country` field will have a valid value as it is from `select`?

Comment: Never trust the client, period.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you should not trust client input.
2. You should be using the country id (use the [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)) and not the name, in case you internationalize your application later.
3. If you are storing the client input in a database, make sure there is a foreign key on the country code they input to a table with all of the country codes. That way their bad input would raise an exception and you can display an error message to them. Make sure you parameterize your SQL statements to the database.